# Scroll View zoom stops letting me scroll the whole zoomed image

Tags: swift, storyboard, scrollview, zooming

So I have a view controller that has an image/button on it. If clicked it activates a modal popup over the view controller with the same image on it. The image is over a UIScrollView, and I created a zoom feature for it.

I am able to successfully zoom in on the image and scroll across it several times, until it decides to stop letting me scroll and zoom the entire image, but only the top-left portion of it.

This only happens after I tilt the screen to landscape mode and activate the popup again. It seems the image gets bigger in the popup window.

The constraints are all done in storyboard. I'm not sure if the problem is the constraints, or the code.

[Modal Popup Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGFp7.png)

The Code:

Variables

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var zoomImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var backgroundButton: UIButton!
```

Image Zoom

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    return self.zoomImageView

}
```

Centers Image during orientation change

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape{
        imageView.center = self.view.center

    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait{
        imageView.center = self.view.center
    }
}
```

Modal Popup

```
@IBAction func showImageView(_ sender: Any) {

    animateIn()

}

@IBAction func closeImageView(_ sender: Any) {

    animateOut()

}

func animateIn() {

    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.center = self.view.center

    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    imageView.alpha = 0

    self.backgroundButton.alpha = 0.7

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { 
        self.imageView.alpha = 1
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }

}

func animateOut() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 

        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.imageView.alpha = 0

        self.backgroundButton.alpha = 0

    }, completion: nil)

}
```

I only put code that has possible relevance to the question.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the completion block at the end on the animateOut function.

Instead of:

```
completion: nil
```

It should have been:

```
(success:Bool) in
self.imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Thanks anyway to anyone that took their time to look through my question. I'm glad such an easy solution was found.